# ¿Cómo hacer que la alarma se active correctamente?

Tags: java, android

Mi alarma funciona perfectamente, pero quiero hacer un cambio que no consigo hacer funcionar, ahora mismo funciona así. 
Como veis: **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm**

```
public void setAlarm(int notification_id) throws ParseException {
    System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(editTextFecha.getText().toString()));
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), otra.prueba.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("titulo", editTextNombre.getText().toString());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(),
            notification_id,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

Y yo quiero así, **dd/MM HH:mm**

Es decir, que se active siempre el día, mes y hora que este marcada sin importar el año que sea

Lo he intentado así, pero no funciona, siempre se activa al instante de guardarla. Como veréis mi alarma se activa por lo que escriba en `editTextFecha`

```
public void setAlarm(int notification_id) throws ParseException {
    System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(editTextFecha.getText().toString()));
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), otra.prueba.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("titulo", editTextNombre.getText().toString());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(),
            notification_id,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no tome en cuenta el año que es de forma correcta?

Answer (score 0):

Si te entiendo bien, esperas del `AlarmManager` un comportamiento parecido a `cron`, pensando que el formato del dato te permite instalar alarmas diarias/semanales etc. Un `Date`, `Calendar` o un sello de tiempo siempre representa **una** fecha y hora concreta, ni un rango, ni un patrón.

El `AlarmManager` internamente trabaja con sellos de tiempo de época (milisegundos pasados desde Jueves, 1. de Enero 1970, UTC).

Tienes que calcular la fecha y hora para la próxima vez que tu alarma se debe activar, y cuando pasa eso, reponerlo con la siguiente fecha y hora etc.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, podrías ponerme un ejemplo de `cron` para guiarme un poco? @StefanNolde